# Wait for ethernet cable plug-in/plug-out event under Linux?

Tags: linux, ethernet

I know that I can poll the link state via the SIOCETHTOOL/ETHTOOL_GLINK ioctl but this would require to endlessly request the state. The same goes for parsing /var/log/messages. So my questin is, is there any way under Linux to wait on a state change of the ethernet cable from userspace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [`ifplugd`](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/ifplugd/#overview)?

> `ifplugd` is a Linux daemon which will automatically configure your ethernet device **when a cable is plugged in and automatically unconfigure it if the cable is pulled**. This is useful on laptops with onboard network adapters, since it will only configure the interface when a cable is really connected.

(There is also `netplugd`, but it was [discontinued](http://people.debian.org/~enrico/netplugd.html).)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was just interested how to do this myself (and not a complete program) but I might dig through the ifplugd code and see how it is done there.

Comment: Looks like NETLINK allows me to do what I want (found out by looking into ifplugd). Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, you're welcome. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The solution of sr_ is better than mine, but you could use those ioctls with `sleep` to avoid the endless stressing of the resources. Write a loop which investigates if there is the questioned link up/down, then do something/nothing in either cases, and then `sleep` a few seconds. It will generate just a little load on your system.