# Execute a script on ethernet connection/disconnection with systemd

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

I have an embedded device that will connect with systemd-networkd to a DHCP server if connected to the local network and will fall back to being a DHCP server if not. I didn't implement it yet but plan using the answer described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309046/114497 .

This answer points to use a script that will be started on boot. I was wondering what if the user unplugs the network cable and connects it to a PC at runtime, he'd need to restart the board for the script to start. So the question is: is there a way to start a script when there's an interface change with systemd?

PS: I tried using [networkd-dispatcher](https://gitlab.com/craftyguy/networkd-dispatcher) without success. I tried restarting the `systemd-networkd` service, unplug the ethernet cable but the script I wrote located in `/usr/lib/networkd-dispatcher` is not executed.

Comment: Ethernet connect/disconnect events are availabinle via NETLINK, see e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33847/wait-for-ethernet-cable-plug-in-plug-out-event-under-linux) (answer proposes to use `ifplugd`). I have no idea if systemd listens to NETLINK events for network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518782/120919) explain what can be done with systemd when network changes...

There are many alternative solution, but a direct simple solution only with systemd is not implemented as of 06/2019

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt my `net-o-matic` script, which currently watches for `DOWN` to look for `UP`. Start it from an `@reboot` `root` `crontab` entry.

I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.